# Two-Way SSL Connection

Tags: api, ssl, crypto

I need to make a 2-way SSL connection to a particular service.  In addition, the password for the service is a cryptographically signed long of the current datetime.  In Salesforce, I can create a self signed cert and add it to the request, but I can't get the signature because Cyrpto.sign needs the private key.  If I create my own key pair, I can't find a way to add my personal certificate to the request.

Thoughts anyone?